# JS Framework for CSS3 translate3d ,animation support

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I am looking for a framework which provides css3 animation support for translate3d(x,y,z), 
I have looked at the best ones i.e. jquery.transit.js and move.js, but this does not solve my purpose.

Comment: "but this does not solve my purpose." -- what is your purpose then? It's hard to suggest an alternative without knowing how the obvious options fall short.

Comment: translate3d and matrix3d implementations are pretty buggy in most of browsers (even the same browser in different platform.) So you may need to try some other methods other than CSS3.

Comment: @JanDvorak Its clearly mentioned translate3d(x,y,z) is what i need, the mentioned frameworks only allows translate(x,y).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such library that will solve the puprose i think, what I did was implement my own logic, by changing the style information using loops and delay.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Traqball.js`. It's a tiny Javascript library which facilitates working with css3 in a javascript environment. Of course it only works on browsers which support CSS3.

https://github.com/dirkweber/traqball.js